# Get value other than input polymer+laravel

Tags: laravel, polymer, laravel-5, paper-elements

I am trying to use laravel with polymer. I have built a form that looks like this

```
    <form action="{{ url('settings/update') }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <h4>Choose your theme</h4>          
            <paper-radio-group selected="1">
              <paper-radio-button name="1" label="Theme Default"></paper-radio-button><br/>
              <paper-radio-button name="2" label="Theme Violet"></paper-radio-button><br/>
              <paper-radio-button name="3" label="Theme Orange"></paper-radio-button><br/>
            </paper-radio-group><br/>
        <button type="submit" class="mui-btn mui-btn-primary">Change Theme</button>
    </form>
```

But I have no idea how to retrieve those fields in my controller. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Form elements don't know how to work with custom elements like `paper-radio-button`. You could replace your form with [`ajax-form`](https://github.com/rnicholus/ajax-form) or use some JavaScript to handle the form submit event, gather up the values, and send the request yourself.